# Family Motto: Interpreting Translator Results

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, translation-check

The following phrase is assumed to be correctly noted from an O.E. church inscription, probably dating to at least the 15th century.

> Tune Desiuis Esse Noli Gloiare

Google and many other online translators on the search pages (which apparently use the same engine) have this as:

> Don't Be Abandoned Tune

The same translation occurs when `Gloiare` is omitted. Removing `Tune` instead gets the following:

> You cease to be, do not glorify

From Whitaker's, the output gets the following:

> ne                   TACKON
> -ne = is it not that (enclitic); or ...(introduces a question or alternative); tu                   PRON   5 2 NOM S C
> tu                   PRON   5 2 VOC S C                  you (sing.);
> thou/thine/thee/thy (PERS); yourself/thyself (REFLEX);
>
> Desiuis                          ========   UNKNOWN
>
> ess.e                VPAR   3 1 VOC S M PERF PASSIVE PPL edo, edere,
> edi, essus  V (3rd) TRANS   [XXXCO]   es.se                V      7 3
> PRES ACTIVE  INF 0 X      Early    edo, esse, -, -  V TRANS   [XXXCO]
> eat/consume/devour; eat away (fire/water/disease); destroy; spend
> money on food .esse                V      5 1 PRES ACTIVE  INF 0 X
> sum, esse, fui, futurus  V   [XXXAX]   be; exist; (also used to form
> verb perfect passive tenses) with NOM PERF PPL
>
> nol.i                V      6 2 PRES ACTIVE  IMP 2 S     nolo, nolle,
> nolui, -  V   [XXXAX]   be unwilling; wish not to; refuse to;
>
> Gloiare                          ========   UNKNOWN

Can any of these results be used to form a plausible translation?
Thanks.

Comment: That text was definitely not correctly transcribed. For one, the last word should obviously be *gloriare*. The part before it is likely *si vis esse* (if you want to be). There rest is a bit mysterious. It would be very helpful to have a picture.

Comment: Thanks, suspected as much- then it is a trip overseas for the snapshot.

Comment: *Tune desinis esse? Noli gloriari*. Maybe. Still seems like it's missing something.

Comment: Update: Google translate now has "Tune Desuius Esse Noli Gloiare" as _Don't Be Alone Don't Be Glorious_, whereas "Tune Desuius Esse Noli **Gloriare**" comes back as _Don't Be Afraid To Be Normal_. Beginning to make some sense.